# Собрать все id в массив и проверить условие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите! Пытаюсь методом `each()` и `push()` собрать массив `id` и передать в условие для сравнения...
Делаю так:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var $mainBox = jQuery('.team-about');
  jQuery('.item a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkTeamMember = jQuery(this).attr('name');
    getTeam(linkTeamMember);
  });

  function getTeam(linkTeamMember) {
    $mainBox.animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    }, 100);
    var id = [];
    jQuery('.team-about').each(function() {
      id.push(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
    });
    if (linkTeamMember == id) {
      jQuery("#" + id).removeClass("visible");
      jQuery("#" + id).addClass("visible");
      $mainBox.animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 300);
    } else {
      jQuery('.team-about').removeClass("visible");
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.item-photo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: flex;
}

.img-block {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <a name="1" href="#">
    <div class="item-photo" style="background-color: #000;">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <a name="2" href="#">
    <div class="item-photo" style="background-color: #000;">
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="1" class="team-about hide">
  <div class="img-block" style="background-color: #777;">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="2" class="team-about hide">
  <div class="img-block" style="background-color: #777;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Смысл в чем: по клику на на ссылку в блоке `item` передается значение `name`, далее это значение сравнивается с `id` другого блока и если они совпадают, то блок с классом `.team-about` становится видимым... В чем может быть ошибка, почему не работает данный код? Заранее благодарен.

Comment: массив ID?  !!!!!!

Comment: @Air значений атрибута `name`, которые в свою очередь являются идентификаторами если так понятней...

Comment: У Вас, случайно, не выкидывает $mainBox is not defined?

Comment: Вот здесь ошибка: 'jQuery("#" + id).removeClass("visible");' нет у Вас элементов с таким css-селектором. У вас есть name. А оно != id

Comment: @Дмытрык если даже этого селектора изначально нет, я его добавляю далее, так что это не фатальная "ошибка" из-за которой не работал бы код, а по поводу name!=id с чего вы взяли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function() {
var $mainBox = jQuery('.team-about');
jQuery('.item a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linkTeamMember = jQuery(this).attr('name');
    getTeam(linkTeamMember);
});

function getTeam(linkTeamMember) {
    $mainBox.each(function() {
        let id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        if (linkTeamMember === id) {
            jQuery("#" + id).removeClass("hide").addClass('visible');
        } else {
            jQuery("#" + id).addClass("hide").removeClass("visible");
        }
    });
}

});
```